# string ressource extraction for kotlin in android studio?

Tags: android, string, intellij-idea, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

So the only thing I see in Android Studio (3.0 Beta 6) when I alt-enter is a very useless "adjust code style settings" option.

[image: adjust code style settings]

This is very inconvenient.

There SHOULD be that feature in there, somewhere, since [this issue, here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11715#tab=History) has been marked "fixed", and true enough, if I "Help->find action"-search it, I do find an intent

[image: toggled-on intent]

But this doesn't do anything. How do I get this to work?

Comment: Looks like you have the entire assignment expression selected. Please try putting the caret on the string constant instead.

Comment: @yole Really?! I tried putting the carret at the end of the string, but that didn't work. You really have to put it ON the string, as in "in-between the quotation marks"... Thanks. Want to make an answer out of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action works if you put the editor caret inside the string literal (between the quotation marks).